# Detect newlines without preceded characters

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to detect newlines in PHP and replace them with `<br>` which are not preceded by `</ul>`, `<ul>`or `</li>`.

```
te
<ul>
<li>iasd</li>
<li>asd</li>
</ul>
ja
123
```

should result in

```
te<br>
<ul>
<li>iasd</li>
<li>asd</li>
</ul>
ja<br>
123<br>
```

The Regex I came up with so far `(^|^.|.[^((\/li>)|<\/ul>|<ul>)])\r?\n` works, but also is triggered when there only is a `>` in front of the new line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: There wont be any title or class attributes in those elements so I don't think those answers affect me? I have total controll over the HTML

Comment: You missed the point of the post.  You shouldn't use regex for this.  Instead I would parse the data as HTML, then determine where you want to insert `<br>`

Comment: So, what you mean to say is that you treat the HTML as plain text and the only "HTML" is substrings between `<` and `>` that have no `<` and `>` inside them, right? Pleae add this information to the question then.

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~<ul>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?ul>)[^<]*)*</ul>\s*(*SKIP)(*F)|$~sm', '<br/>', $text)`, see https://3v4l.org/2JnT2

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing:

```
(?<!(?:<ul>)|(?:<\/ul>)|(?:<\/li>))([\n\r]|$)
```

With `<br>\1`

As seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/ypmLAr/2)**

## Explanation:

Using negative lookbehinds and well, lookbehinds in general makes your life much easier. You can learn more abour there here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html